# How to allow CSS in HTML Purifier filtering

Tags: css, htmlpurifier, mahara

I see many questions about HTML Purifier. Most of them explain what I'm looking for, and they f.e. say this:

> Try this:
>
> ```
> $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8'); // replace with your encoding
> $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
> $config->set('CSS.Trusted', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional'); // allow any
> css $config->set('HTML.Allowed','div[style]');
> $config->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'background-color');
> ```

But... in which file do I put the above lines?

I'm sorry to say, but HTML Purifier documentation is impossible to understand. I have read it many times and still don't understand where to allow CSS code and how to allow it.

A demo file would also be nice, or at least a good instruction of WHICH files to edit.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hi, Richard! How are you using HTML Purifier right now? You should have a file somewhere that already has a `$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();` line in it, which you would then extend with the lines altering it. If you don't have that file yet, can you explain how you're presently using HTML Purifier in your code?

Comment: It's part of Mahara (mahara.org), an open source digital portfolio system. This system allows you to create webpages and style them with CSS, but most CSS is being stripped by HTMLPurifier. I can't find the right place to set the allow and deny rules for CSS.

Comment: I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with Mahara, but I've gone ahead and tagged your question with that. Perhaps an expert can help you out with how HTML Purifier has been integrated there (although some quick googling suggests the configuration is inaccessible).